# How to convert HTML back to markdown?

Tags: html, perl, markdown

I am looking for a way to convert [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) to HTML and back, more out of interest than real need. I am aware of the loss of information on such a conversion.

I hope for an [html2text.pl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?html2text.pl) like conversion. If there is no such utility in Perl I would try to take this script as a base for a CPAN module.

Comment: ...and the question is...?

Comment: It is pretty big a heading isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML::WikiConverter::Markdown](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aWikiConverter%3a%3aMarkdown) seems up to the task.

Comment: @matthiaskrull Seems, you don't love it - because enough enter `markdown`into the CPAN's search field... ;) :)

Comment: I guess I gave up to early. On metacpan it came up last on the first page.. so no excuse for me :/

Answer (score 4):

There you go: [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) can convert almost anything to anything. Sorry, no perl though.

Comment: Creating a module that wraps this tool (or its underlying library if any) could be useful.

Comment: There are Python and Ruby bindings (they are simply calling the `pandoc` command). If I remember correctly you can build `Pandoc` as a shared library, that's a bit more flexible, IMHO.